# How can i get a dropdown button in my PHP Codeigniter form?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, button, dropdown

I'm making a form to insert records into my database and i'm trying to create a dropdown button in it.

This is the code of my form: -------------------------------------

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Product/product_form'); ?>" method="post">

        <table class="calendar_table">
        <tr>

          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'product_naam', 'name'=>'product_naam', 'placeholder' => '1. Naam van het cadeau', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'product_categorie', 'name'=>'product_categorie', 'placeholder' => 'Kies een categorie', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'name'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'placeholder' => '3.Kies een stad', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>

          <?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'product_foto', 'name'=>'product_foto', 'placeholder' => '4. Upload foto', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td><?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'textarea','id'=>'product_beschrijving', 'name'=>'product_beschrijving', 'placeholder' => '5. Vertel iets over dit cadeau', 'size'=>25));?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadeau aanbieden!</button>
         </td>
        </tr>     
      </table>
    </form>
```

---

This is the input type field that i want to replace with a dropdown button:

```
<td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'product_categorie', 'name'=>'product_categorie', 'placeholder' => 'Kies een categorie', 'size'=>25));?></td>
```

Can someone help me with that?
Thanks

Comment: What can we help you with? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not start with a little HTML basics? 
[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

```
<?php
  $selectField = "
    <select name="mySelectField">
        <option value="xxxx">discription1</option>
        <option value="yyyy">discription2</option>
    </select>
  ";
  // wherever needed
  echo($selectField);
?>
```

Comment: yes but how can I do that in <?php echo form_input(array(

Comment: For better product results, please do learn some HTML. Very usefull if you build forms.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a simple google search gives a lot of results, for instance: https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-form-dropdown/

```
$options = array(
'Computer Science Engineering' => 'Computer Science Engineering',
'Electronics and Comm. Engineering' => 'Electronics and Comm. Engineering',
'Mechanical Engineering' => 'Mechanical Engineering',
'Civil Engineering' => 'Civil Engineering',
);

echo form_dropdown('Department', $options, 'Computer Science Engineering', 'class="dropdown_box1"');
```